# What is the best practice about microservice architecture for consuming many stored procedures in the same database?

Tags: stored-procedures, database-design, architecture, microservices

I have to build a micro service for my company, the backend is an Oracle database, but the micro service must consume five (5) stored procedures that already exist in the database (as shown in the screenshot). The database architecture can't change.

My question is: must I build only one (1) micro service that consumes these five(5) stored procedures?

[image: Single microservice accessing multiple stored procedures]

Or must I build five (5) micro services that consume each one of these stored procedures?

[image: Multiple microservices each accessing a single stored procedure]

I'm very confused about making that decision, because in most architecture notes about micro services, one micro service should exist only for one database but this way it wouldn't be a decoupled solution. But the other hand, if I build five micro services, each one using a stored procedure, it would be five services that share the same database or repository of data.

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Referring to my previous answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431836/how-do-i-avoid-tightly-coupling-one-microservice-to-another-microservices-featu/431844#431844 : if it's coupled, it's not really a microservice. If all the microservices are by the same team, it's not a microservice.

Comment: You don't make such decisions by counting the number of stored proceedures you have to deal with. You make them by looking at the usage, deployment, and life cycle scenarios of your system and its parts. So forgive me if that sounds harsh, but: it is IMHO absurd to believe it makes any sense to make a microservice decision by the information presented in this question.

Comment: Both approaches are not wrong. It is perfectly fine for several microservices to use the same database - if they deal with different things and work independently of each other (e.g. one microservice for login and account processing, one for the ticket system, etc.). Does your microservice handle different topics? If so, it should probably be split into separate services. Otherwise, if only handles one specific topic, leave it as in your first picture.

Comment: What is the role of your service? Does it do some processing on the data from the database? I mean, the first question I have seeing the second picture is "why have a service and not query the database directly"? Perhaps with some library helper for interfacing. OTOH, if you need to have any sort of processing involving data from multiple stored procedures, the second picture is out of the window immediately, because it simply doesn't work.

Comment: FWIW, both approaches are more an "API" and less a "microservice"

Comment: Beware that multiple micro services using the same database is just another form of a distributed monolith. Also, "micro" doesn't necessarily mean itty-bitty, eency-weancy. Micro services can still be bigger as long as they are independently deployable and scalable. You will see those terms repeated in answers and comments. A micro service must be **independently deployable and scalable**. That alone can help lead your decision.

Comment: `FWIW, both approaches are more an "API" and less a "microservice"` So call it an "API Gateway", and then it becomes clear that having all the endpoints in the same service is fine, as it's really just a protocol adapter.

Answer (score 64):

I get the feeling that some decision maker in your company heard about the buzzword "micro-service" and decided that you need to have them as well, regardless of if they actually solve a problem you are having.

The primary reason why all notes talk about a separate database for each micro-service is because micro-services are intended to be independently deployable and scalable.

If you find that one feature of your application is much more heavily used than the other features, then if each of the features is implemented by a (proper) micro-service, then you can just run more instances of that one heavily used service. And that can also mean having multiple instances of the database to keep the load on that part of the service within reason.

With your constraint of a fixed database architecture, I would design a single service for that and, independently of whether that service meets all the checkboxes for a micro-service, call it a micro-service (for political reasons).

In short, create the best design given the technical constraints and then slap on the buzz-word labels that people want to see.

Comment: "call it a micro-service (for political reasons)" -- Good reminder to engineers that there are political solutions to software engineering problems

Comment: Different release cycles might also be a good reason to split a service into smaller components.

Comment: @ptyx But a deployment unit includes the database (since code changes will impact the database, and vice versa), so splitting it into many components actually makes it a nightmare to deploy (You will likely need to deploy everything all at the same time anyway...)

Comment: @ArTs IMO that's a characteristic of microservices - easy to change inside, but anything that crosses services requires well defined API, orchestrated rollout, backward compatibility, etc. And that's typically where one should take a step back and design their topology based on APIs, dependencies, unit of change and scalability rather than 'micro' everything because it's sexy. If code changes and DB changes go together, then that should be your unit of deployment. If you got a well defined, stable schema that doesn't need to change much, maybe they're better as separate units.

Answer (score 0):

Micro- and midi-services can often usefully be divided by Topic; sometimes, more coarsely, they can be divided by the Source/ Category/ Lifetime of the data involved.

Some potential scenarios:

- An Entity and closely related data owned by it should typically be a single service. (In the case your 5 stored procs are different CRUD and child accessors).
- A group of topically related entities (eg. Customer, Address and Preferences) may often be a single service.
- Where multiple entities have strong commonality as to lifecycle, you can sometimes consider grouping these into a single "midi service". For example, a group of Reference Data tables or inputs/ outputs to or from external systems.
- Entities which are separate in topic and lifecycle should be separate services.

See:  https://literatejava.com/uncategorized/micro-and-midi-services-how-should-i-divide-my-services/

Answer (score 0):

Although you can not avoid one database, separate your microservice into boundary contexts. The bounded context concept originated in Domain-Driven Design (DDD) circles. It promotes an object-model-first approach to a service, defining a data model that a service is responsible for and is "bound to." In other words, the service owns this data and is responsible for its integrity and mutability.
Take a look at

[https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-a-bounded-context#:~:text=The%20bounded%20context%20concept%20originated,for%20its%20integrity%20and%20mutability](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-a-bounded-context#:%7E:text=The%20bounded%20context%20concept%20originated,for%20its%20integrity%20and%20mutability).

Answer (score 0):

Giving a benefit of doubt and assuming this is just first step moving towards decoupled service architecture at your company.

You can think of a 1 stored procedure as one logical unit of work needed to be completed.  May be the current procs are very complicated and they are doing lots of cross db queries, linked server calls and all possible workflow that does not fit in the expected end goal. in that case someone has to work lot more on data refactoring.

Or may the procs are simple enough that with little modifications they can be lift and shift to their own db along with underlaying data they need. Whatever the case with procs I am guessing someone is thinking about it doing later or at least it's part of the bigger plan.

So I would lean towards one service for one proc so that later when you guys refactor db components it will more or less align with end to end (application+db) independent deployable service architecture.

That is just MPO based on limited information we have here.

Answer (score 0):

To properly design the microservice(s), you need to step back and look at things from a higher level. It's not enough to identify what components you have and what ones you may need to build; you need to consider how and why each component is used and how they relate to other components.

Imagine you live in a one bedroom apartment but will soon move to a much larger house. You have five pieces of furniture in your living room you would like to keep and need to decide what room(s) to move the furniture to. Would you move each piece of furniture to a separate room in the house or would you move them all to the same room? (Pause for a moment to consider how silly that question might sound.) Presumably, the rooms you choose would depend on what those pieces of furniture actually are.

If two pieces of the furniture are a couch and a TV stand, you would likely move them to the new living room so you have a place to sit and watch TV. You might also move the floor lamp to the living room depending upon how much light there is. However, your kitchen table wouldn't need to be in the living room since you would now have a full sized kitchen to put it in. Likewise, your coat rack would go in the foyer of your new house since that's where the front door is.

This is the same approach you should apply to your new microservice(s). What do these stored procedures do? How are they used and how do they relate to each other? If they are all closely related and see similar levels of use, then it would make sense to put only one microservice in front of them. If, however, those stored procedures have nothing in common aside from being in the same database, then it would make sense to create five separate microservices; if you do so, though, you should also discuss splitting the database into smaller pieces as well.

There are many possible ways you could design microservices. The key is to organize the functionality into services where the internal components are closely related but the external components are loosely related (if related at all). This will make the services easier to comprehend and thus easier to maintain. It will also minimize dependencies, making it easier to scale services as you need to.

In short, the ratio of microservices to stored procedures is irrelevant. What matters it that functionality is organized logically. Otherwise, you'll end up in weird scenarios like having a TV you can't sit in front of or a coat rack that isn't anywhere near a door.